# Spring boot : Failed to save List<String>

Tags: spring-boot

Please I'm trying to save List in spring boot I failed to do it.

this is **the entity** :

```
@Column(name="services")
@ElementCollection
@NotBlank
private List<String> services = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is Postman :

[image]

**Postman result :**

[image]

**issue :**

```
: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'
```

I edit the function to save like this :

```
    List<String> lstServices= new ArrayList<>();
    carePost.getServices().forEach(item -> {
        lstServices.add(item);
    });

    carePost.setServices(lstServices);
```

but still same error

**Controller method :**

```
@PostMapping("/addcarepost")
public ResponseEntity<?> createCarePost(@RequestBody CarePost carePost){



    carePost.setCareserviceId(carePost.getCareserviceId());

    List<String> lstServices= new ArrayList<>();

    carePost.getService().forEach(item -> {
        lstServices.add(item);
    });

    carePost.setService(lstServices);


    carePostService.save(carePost);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("CarePost registered successfully!"));
}
```

**ServiceImpl :**

```
@Override
    public CarePost save(CarePost cp) {

        return carePostRepository.save(cp)  ;  }
```

Comment: You added validation annotations and probably tried to outsmart the dependency management by including `javax.validation` as a dependency instead of `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Comment: please how can I solve it

Comment: you posted the Controller I meant the method in the service, by the way. The whole forEach stuff its useless, you are just looping and putting back. Anyway post the Whole CarePost  Dto too.

Comment: i edited, but nothing important is simple save, the whole work i did it in the controller

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to be sure if was a simple save or something more complex.

Comment: put a breakpoint on ` carePostService.save(carePost);`  and see if inside you have all the services.

Comment: service is null

Comment: did you by chance write the getters and setters by hand ? Because the Getters and Setters should be, like getServices/setServices not getService/setService.

Comment: noooooooo,  just i tested different ways that's way

Comment: Sorry what? I didn't understand what u meant

Comment: U asked me about the service and services, I told u it's just  beacause i used diffirent way but when i execute I execute it with one service or services

Comment: before we do proceed with further questions, lets see if I got all the situation right. At the moment when you save, you did check into the `CarePost` entity if services was populated or null. You said was null, right? Then I asked you, how are called the getters and setters of the services property? Other question, can you put the whole entity into the post, instead of just one property?

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `@NotBlank` because:

> `@NotBlank` can be applied only to text values and validates that the property is not null or whitespace.

instead you should use `@NotEmpty` because :

> `@NotEmpty` validates that the property is not null or empty; can be applied to String, Collection, Map or Array values.

If your goal is to verify if in the array are some empty values, you can create a custom validator like shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)  or you can use `List<@NotBlank String> preferences;`

Putting `@NotBlank` (or others validation annotation) at property level, will validate the property itself, if you wanna instead validate the element of a the property (in this case a collection)you have to put the annotation at the same element level (as shown on the top).

Source: [Javax Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

Comment: yeah u r right, I delete it, it save now only one value can't save list of string, please can u check the post  added the function to save into data base

Comment: In the post you said , you keep having the same error of before, are you getting the same error or just doesnt save?

Comment: yes doesn't save , not same error, it save null

Comment: can you post the whole method you call to save ?